# Transform XML to table with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I've a `XML` contains data like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <metadata>
          <item name="Revenue" type="xs:decimal" scale="2" precision="31"/>
          <item name="Month" type="xs:short" precision="1"/>
    </metadata>
    <data>
        <row>
            <value currency="USD">100000</value>
            <value>1</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value currency="USD">200000.16</value>
            <value>2</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value currency="USD">150000.9</value>
            <value>3</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value currency="USD">180000.07</value>
            <value>4</value>
        </row>
    </data>
</dataset>
```

I'd like to convert this `XML` to a `HTML` table like this:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <th style="text-align:left">Revenue</th>
    <th style="text-align:left">Month</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>100000</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>200000.16</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>150000.9</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>180000.07</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Could anyone please tell me how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This stylesheet will do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="dataset">
        <table border="1"><xsl:apply-templates /></table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="metadata">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th style="text-align:left"><xsl:value-of select="item[1]/@name"/></th>
            <th style="text-align:left"><xsl:value-of select="item[2]/@name"/></th>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row">
        <tr><xsl:apply-templates /></tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="value">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is how it works:

The processor will read each node in a template. Starting with the root `/` (it has an implicit template for that) it will process each node and if there is a matching template it will transform the node according to the template.

The template can then allow the recursive processing of the other nodes if it has a `<xsl:apply-templates>` element in it. So the processor finds `dataset`, matches it with the first template, adds the `<table>` elements, and inside the table, sends the processor to the next template. It will process `metadata` and finish that subtree, then it will process `data`. Since `data` has no explicit matching template, it again uses a default implicit template which matches every reachable node that doesn't have an explicit template. That template allows the processing of the rest of the tree, the `row`, which contains an `apply-templates`, and the `value`.

Templates are processed several times to render the resulting HTML.

Comment: I tried your code but why all the <table><tr><td> tags are gone?

Comment: If you try the code with the source XML you posted, it generates what you expected. If it's not working, perhaps your source has changes. In that case you need to adapt it, since the XSL depends of the source structure.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault. I found after I changed namespace from xmlns:xs="http://www.cognos.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance  to xmlns="http://www.cognos.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance, the transformation fails.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the transformation. If it is a standard schema instance declaration, it should be `www.w3.org` not `cognos.org`. You declare the schema instance namespace if you need to use one of the four schema instance attributes in your code (such as `type`), and it should be used with a prefix (usually `xsi`). And if you have a schema instance namespace declared, you also need a XML Schema namespace (usually with a `xs` prefix`), since any of the four attributes are practically useless without it. But that's another problem. Don't use those namespaces without a prefix.